# How to specify my table to insert data as time in minutes and second into a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been struggling for several hours now and I have not been able to find the solution to my problem. This is an assignment, but I am stuck in this part.

```
 CREATE TABLE Trip
(
 Trip_Id                SERIAL,
 Origin                 VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
 Destination            VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
 Date_Time_Picked       TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL    DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
 Estimated_Time         TIME            NOT NULL    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,
 Price                  DECIMAL         NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(Trip_Id)
);



INSERT INTO Trip (Origin, Destination, Estimated_Time, Price  )
VALUES ('Hialeah' ,'Miami Beach', 30:00, 40.00);
```

The insert statement in postgreSQL shows a error because the time format. The column Estimated_Time is supposed to store the time in minutes and seconds, but the compiler shows an error because interprets 30:00 as hours and seconds. How can I handle the input of the user to save 30:00 as 30 minutes and 0 seconds. The Trip table can be modified, obviously, the insert statement requires a conversion or cast from  '30:00' to Time type, but I am lost in how to do it. Unfortunately, books do not explain how this is done. I would greatly appreciate any hint or example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd try `'00:30:00'` as time literal, or perhaps `TIME'00:30:00'`.

Comment: What exactly is `estimated_time`? The arrival time ("at noon") or the _duration_ of the trip?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I'm going to fix it. Without a doubt, a hint can save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: estimated_time is the time that a trip is supposed to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as pointed out by  a_horse_with_no_name  and jarlh,
Estimated_Time is the duration of the trip, so the format should be interval

```
CREATE TABLE trip (
  trip_id SERIAL,
  origin VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  destination VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  date_time_picked TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT 'now'::text::date NOT NULL,
  estimated_time INTERVAL,
  price NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT trip_pkey PRIMARY KEY(trip_id)
)
```

and the insert sould be

```
INSERT INTO Trip (Origin, Destination, Estimated_Time, Price  )
VALUES ('Hialeah' ,'Miami Beach', '00:30:00', 40.00);
```